# How to use addEventListener to change HTML layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm currently trying to use EventListener on click on HTML page1 to toggle `style.display` of an image from `none` to `block` on page2, is this possible?

This is the HTML that the `EventListener` listens to.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/styles/style.css">
<script src="../public/scripts/selection.js"></script>

  <form action = "/search" method = "POST" id="submitMessage" class="field has-addons">
            <select name ="species">
              <option value="" disabled selected>--Please Select a Species--</option>
              <option class = "dog" value="Dog">Dog</option>
              <option class = "cat" value="Cat">Cat</option>
            </select>
  </form>
```

This is the JavaScript that should change `style.display`:

```
const selection = () => {
  const dog = document.querySelector('.dog');
  const cat = document.querySelector('.cat');
  
  dog.addEventListener('click', () => {
      dogPic.style.display = block;
    });

 cat.addEventListener('click', () => {
      catPic.style.display = block;
    });
}

selection();
```

And this is the CSS:

```
    .dog{
  
     }

    .cat{
  
     }

    .dogPic{
  display: none;
     }

.catPic{
  display: none;
    }
```

Here is the second HTML where the picture should change according to what option is clicked.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/styles/style.css">

      <div class="dogPic">
        <img src="../public/images/dogSpecies.png" style="max-height: 130px;">
      </div>
      <div class="catPic">
        <img src="../public/images/catSpecies.png" style="max-height: 130px;">
      </div>
```

I didn't put the JavaScript on the second HTML.

I'm doing this in Node.js, but the JavaScript is normal JavaScript without any Node.js function. Should this work? Or is this impossible?

```
[![This is the directory structure, index.ejs is where the select option is, species.ejs is where I want the picture to change according to what option is clicked on][1]][1]
```

Comment: Very possible. Also, I do not think you need CSS since you dynamically access to `.style` of elements. How did you create your project?

Comment: @GyuHyeon Choi I learnt to use eventlistener through youtube and the person was using css. I'm not too sure what you mean by how i created my project, I uses nodejs. Is there anything wrong in my code? should it work or am i using some commands wrong?

Comment: I am not sure how `dogPic` and `catPic` are available inside an event listener. Besides that, it seems pretty fine. Anyway, it is not your entire code so I'm not sure. I want to reproduce. Did you use `npm init`? Or, something like` webpack`?

Comment: Are you using `npx http-server`?

Comment: I am not using npx http-server, im using express, how would that change the code you provide. Also I though I can ascess dogPic and catPic since I put it in css. Should I alsouse document.querySelector to reference them? Thanks a lot

Comment: I believe there is no CSS styles you can access. Each DOM element has its CSS style. You should access a `div` element of the class `dogPic` or `catPic`. Then you can change its CSS style by changing properties in `.style`. For further help, you would better put your project structure, how to serve it and the YouTuve link.

Comment: You do not have `app.js`. Is `code.js` your entry?

Comment: yes, code.js is my entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `code.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html')
})

app.post('/search', (req, res) => {
  res.render('species.ejs', {species: req.body.species})
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

#### `public/index.html`

```
<form action="/search" method="POST" id="submitMessage">
  <select name ="species">
    <option value="" disabled selected>--Please Select a Species--</option>
    <option class="dog" value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option class="cat" value="Cat">Cat</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script src="scripts/selection.js"></script>
```

#### `public/scripts/selection.js`

```
const selection = () => {
  const dog = document.querySelector('.dog');
  const cat = document.querySelector('.cat');
  
  dog.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('submitMessage').submit();
  }); 

  cat.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('submitMessage').submit();
  }); 
}

selection();
```

From `public/index.html` (probably http://localhost:3000/), you make a form request to (probably) to http://localhost:3000/search.

The string `'Dog'` or `'Cat'` is passed as the variable `species`. Then you can dynamically `render` your page `views/species.ejs` by defining `style`s based on the variable.

#### `views/species.ejs`

```
<div style="display: <%= species === 'Dog' ? 'block' : 'none' %>">
  <img src="../public/images/dogSpecies.png" style="max-height: 130px;">
</div>
<div style="display: <%= species === 'Cat' ? 'block' : 'none' %>">
  <img src="../public/images/catSpecies.png" style="max-height: 130px;">
</div>
```

I do not know what you exactly want to do, however, since Express is a back-end framework, dynamic page rendering is not that suitable compared to other front-end frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how do you serve your project so I guessed and tried.

My project structure:

```
html/index.html
public
 ├ styles/style.css (empty)
 └ scripts/selection.js
```

And I serve it using

```
npx http-server .
```

So I can browse to http://127.0.0.1:8080.

`html/index.html` is pretty much like yours but the `script` element was moved below the `form` element.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/styles/style.css">

<form action = "/search" method = "POST" id="submitMessage" class="field has-addons">
  <select name ="species">
    <option value="" disabled selected>--Please Select a Species--</option>
    <option class = "dog" value="Dog">Dog</option>
    <option class = "cat" value="Cat">Cat</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script src="../public/scripts/selection.js"></script>

<div class="dogPic">
  <img src="../public/images/dogSpecies.png" style="max-height: 130px;">
</div>
<div class="catPic">
  <img src="../public/images/catSpecies.png" style="max-height: 130px;">
</div>
```

`public/scripts/selection.js` is:

```
const selection = () => {
  const dog = document.querySelector('.dog');
  const cat = document.querySelector('.cat');

  dog.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let dogPic = document.querySelector('.dogPic');
    let catPic = document.querySelector('.catPic');
    dogPic.style.display = 'block';
    catPic.style.display = 'none';
  });
    
  cat.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let dogPic = document.querySelector('.dogPic');
    let catPic = document.querySelector('.catPic');
    dogPic.style.display = 'none';
    catPic.style.display = 'block';
  });
}   

selection();
```

Variables outside the scope of an event listener are not reachable so you have to assign DOM element inside it. (Note that `dogPic` and `catPic` are not CSS element (my CSS is empty), but `div` elements.) Then you can programmatically change its `style`.

Many frameworks support using Javascript objects as if CSS, however, you cannot treat plain CSS as if Javascript variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This makes a lot of sense, but I want the selection(.cat or.dog) and the dogPic to be on two different HTML, so when you click the select option of cat or dog on one website, it will redirect you to another website that will have the HTML with dogPic or catPic. Can I just use the code provided and put the select option and the pictures on two different HTML?

Comment: @JeffLo Without `script` element in the 2nd HTML, I don't think so. You need Javascript to make dynamic pages.

Comment: So if I put script element in the 2nd HTML how would I do it? would i just include the script <script src="../public/scripts/selection.js"></script> in the second HTML and it will work?

Comment: Without any framework, you cannot share Javascript variables across different HTML files unless you pass it throught external storage. But I believe `express` can make your HTML files as if a one single HTML file, thus SPA. So you definitely can do it. If you share your project structure (directory structure), it would be helpful.

Comment: I have uploaded the project structure as a picture, I forgot I started using ejs due to the implementation of other features, how much would it change how this will work?